# More Management VLANS for a switch

Tags: cisco, switch, vlan, telnet

I created a management interface in vlan 99 to telnet the switch (2900 series). I also wanted to configure another management interface for the same switch from the computer belongs to the different vlan 101. I can configure and bring the line state up but could not ping the switch. But i found out there should be only one active management interface for a switch. So, I have used 3000 series (multiport) switch but still could not achieve that because i used the network (192.168.1.64/27 for vlan 99) and 192.168.1.100/27 for vlan 101) so getting masking error. How can i have two management interface from two hosts belonging to different vlans at the same time?